# x86 - Why does the compiler insert a seemingly meaningless JMP to the next instruction?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I'm trying to learn the relationship between C++ and x86, and have been looking at the corresponding assembly instructions of some C++ code. What caught my eye though, is that there seems to be multiple JMPs to the very next instruction. Isn't this just wasting space and clock cycles?

The source code is pretty straightforward, just a simple game from a textbook.

```
// Lost Fortune
// A personalized adventure!

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    const int GOLD_PIECES = 900;
    int adventurers, killed, survivors;
    string leader;

    // Get info.
    cout << "Welcome fo Lost Fortune\n\n";
    cout << "Please enter the following for your personalized adventure\n";

    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> adventurers;

    cout << "Enter a number, smaller than the first: ";
    cin >> killed;

    survivors = adventurers - killed;

    cout << "Enter your last name: ";
    cin >> leader;


    // Tell story.
    cout << "\nA brave group of " << adventurers << " set out on a quest ";
    cout << "-- in search of the lost treasure of the Ancient Dwarves. ";
    cout << "The group was led by that legendary rogue,  " << leader << ".\n";
    cout << "\n Along the way, a bang of marauding ogres ambushed the party. ";
    cout << "All fought bravely under the command of " << leader;
    cout << ", and the ogres were defeated, but at a cost. ";
    cout << "Of the adventurers, " << killed << " were vanquished, ";
    cout << "leaving just " << survivors << " in the group.\n";

    cout << "\nThe party was about to give up all hope. ";
    cout << "But while laying the deceased to rest, ";
    cout << "they stumbled upon the buried fortune. ";
    cout << "So the adventurers split " << GOLD_PIECES << " gold pieces. ";
    cout << leader << " held on to the extra " << (GOLD_PIECES % survivors);
    cout << " pieces to keep things fair of course.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

An excerpt of the assembly is as follows. Notice that there are several JMPs that go to the very next instruction, at address 00002053, 00002076 etc. The opcode for these JMPs is E9 00 00 00 00 if that helps.

```
00002035         mov        eax, dword [ebp+var_64]                             ; CODE XREF=_main+148
00002038         lea        ecx, dword [eax-0x1f91+0x3c60]                      ; "Welcome fo Lost Fortune\\n\\n"
0000203e         mov        edx, esp
00002040         mov        dword [edx+4], ecx
00002043         mov        ecx, dword [eax-0x1f91+__ZNSt3__14coutE_400c]       ; __ZNSt3__14coutE_400c
00002049         mov        dword [edx], ecx
0000204b         call       imp___symbol_stub___ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc ; std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
00002050         mov        dword [ebp+var_74], eax
00002053         jmp        loc_2058

             loc_2058:
00002058         mov        eax, dword [ebp+var_64]                             ; CODE XREF=_main+211
0000205b         lea        ecx, dword [eax-0x1f91+0x3c7a]                      ; "Please enter the following for your personalized adventure\\n"
00002061         mov        edx, esp
00002063         mov        dword [edx+4], ecx
00002066         mov        ecx, dword [eax-0x1f91+__ZNSt3__14coutE_400c]       ; __ZNSt3__14coutE_400c
0000206c         mov        dword [edx], ecx
0000206e         call       imp___symbol_stub___ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc ; std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
00002073         mov        dword [ebp+var_78], eax
00002076         jmp        loc_207b

             loc_207b:
0000207b         mov        eax, dword [ebp+var_64]                             ; CODE XREF=_main+246
0000207e         lea        ecx, dword [eax-0x1f91+0x3cb6]                      ; "Enter a number: "
00002084         mov        edx, esp
00002086         mov        dword [edx+4], ecx
00002089         mov        ecx, dword [eax-0x1f91+__ZNSt3__14coutE_400c]       ; __ZNSt3__14coutE_400c
0000208f         mov        dword [edx], ecx
00002091         call       imp___symbol_stub___ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc ; std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
00002096         mov        dword [ebp+var_7C], eax
00002099         jmp        loc_209e

             loc_209e:
0000209e         mov        eax, esp                                            ; CODE XREF=_main+281
000020a0         lea        ecx, dword [ebp+var_44]
000020a3         mov        dword [eax+4], ecx
000020a6         mov        ecx, dword [ebp+var_64]
000020a9         mov        edx, dword [ecx-0x1f91+__ZNSt3__13cinE_4008]        ; __ZNSt3__13cinE_4008
000020af         mov        dword [eax], edx
000020b1         call       imp___symbol_stub___ZNSt3__113basic_istreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEErsERi ; std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(int&)
000020b6         mov        dword [ebp+var_80], eax
000020b9         jmp        loc_20be
```

Why would the compiler do this? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: did you compile with optimizations on?

Comment: What level of optimizations are you using?  And what compiler?

Comment: I compiled with g++, only flags are -g -m32

Comment: Compile with `-O3` as an added option for a higher level of optimizations.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks, adding the -O3 flag did remove the JMPs! Do you know why they were in there in the first place though? Isn't the optimized version just better in every way?

Comment: What version of g++ are you using out of curiosity? (should be able to tell from `g++ -v` ?

Comment: And is this a Windows version of the g++ compiler? I guess i should ask what OS you are on?

Comment: @MichaelPetch it's actually the mac version, the output of `$ g++ -v` is `Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

Comment: @Bobby Bob  "Isn't the optimized version just better in every way?" - No. When you build without optimization the compilers priority is to generate code that's easy to debug, not code that runs fast. Optimized code may run faster but it's extremely difficult to debug. So if your intention is to debug the code to find a bug, the unoptimized version is almost always preferable.

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks, it all makes sense now :)

Comment: TIL: A group of ogres is called a 'bang.'  Presumably due to their use of clubs on their enemies, rather than the amount of hair that hangs into their eyes.

Comment: @JesperJuhl You might want to compile with `-Og` for best debugging experience.

Comment: @BobbyBob: note that you're not actually using gcc or g++ *per se* - on Mac OS X gcc and g++ are just symbolic links to clang and clang++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you build without optimization the compilers priority is to generate code that's easy to debug and matches the original source code as closely as possible, not code that runs fast.

When optimizing (for example using `-O3`) the compiler's job is to make the code fast and it won't do silly things with `JMP`s like you observed.

Optimized code may run faster but it's extremely difficult to debug. So if your intention is to debug the code to find a bug, the unoptimized version is almost always preferable.

Comment: That's all true but I don't think it answers the question - why were the jumps inserted in the first place?

Comment: Optimized code is not difficult to debug. It just takes a little getting used to.

Comment: Without optimization, a compiler may choose to prioritize giving you your executable quickly, which can mean "throwing lumps of code together using jumps" rather than spending time relocating code to be jump-free (as it would when optimizing for speed or size).  Getting the executable quickly is important, as it reduces the time to getting your unit-test results that tell you what you need to fix next...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for those jumps, it is compiler specific. A snippet of the assembly code generated by Visual Studio as a debug build.

```
; Line 19
        push    OFFSET ??_C@_0BK@OBIFJKE@Welcome?5fo?5Lost?5Fortune?6?6?$AA@
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A
        push    eax
        call    ??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z ; std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >
        add     esp, 8
; Line 20
        push    OFFSET ??_C@_0DM@EEOOGOCI@Please?5enter?5the?5following?5for?5y@
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A
        push    eax
        call    ??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z ; std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >
        add     esp, 8
; Line 22
        push    OFFSET ??_C@_0BB@ONCLGIPK@Enter?5a?5number?3?5?$AA@
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A
        push    eax
        call    ??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z ; std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >
        add     esp, 8
; Line 23
```

The assembly code as seen during debug:

```
        push    offset string "Welcome fo Lost Fortune\n\n" (417B88h) 
        mov     eax,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (41B354h)] 
        push    eax  
        call    std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (41115Eh) 
        add     esp,8 
        push    offset string "Please enter the following for y"... (417B40h) 
        mov     eax,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (41B354h)] 
        push    eax  
        call    std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (41115Eh) 
        add     esp,8 
        push    offset string "Enter a number: " (417B2Ch) 
        mov     eax,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (41B354h)] 
        push    eax  
        call    std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (41115Eh) 
        add     esp,8
```

Answer (score -1):

They might be to help you single step during debugging, because these correspond to each statement at source level. Although, if I were gcc I would rather insert int 3 and worry about other things later.

Comment: Not really an answer - could just be a comment.